# Dwolla : InvalidTokenType : The requested endpoint requires an account token

Tags: meteor, dwolla

Now I am switching to production. And getting “InvalidTokenType : The requested endpoint requires an account token” error while creating new customer.

```
  'getDwollaAccount' : function(userId) {
   var dwollaCredentials = getDwollaCreden();
   const client = new dwolla.Client({
     key         : dwollaCredentials.appKey,
     secret      : dwollaCredentials.appSecret,
     environment : 'production' // optional - defaults to production
   }); // call dwolla initial api

   client.auth.client()
   .then(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(appToken) {

    var userFound = 
    Meteor.users.findOne({'_id':userId,'profile.dwollaLocation':''});
    if(userFound){
        var requestBody = {
          firstName : userFound.profile.firstname,
          lastName  : userFound.profile.lastname,
          email     : userFound.emails[0].address
        };
        appToken
            .post('customers', requestBody)
            .then( 
                (res)=> {
                    var dwollaLocation = res.headers.get('location');;      
                    return Promise.resolve(dwollaLocation);
                }
            )
            .then(
                Meteor.bindEnvironment((dloc) =>{ 
                        return Promise.resolve(dloc);
                })
            )
            .catch(Meteor.bindEnvironment((error) => {
               console.log(error);
                              }));  
    } // end of user found
    })
    );
    },
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If this code worked in the Dwolla Sandbox, it's probably not a problem with your code. Please contact your Dwolla account manager to help resolve.

If you're not in a contract with Dwolla and/or you don't have any account manager, you can use the contact form to help get that process initiated: [Contact Dwolla](http://www.dwolla.com/contact)

Thanks!